# learnyounode FILTERED LS

Tags: node.js

There are many ways to write this code but I can't understand why my version is not working.

The program should take 2 arguments from the command line. The first is the path to a folder with files, and the second arg is a file extention. The output should print only the files with the same extention as the second argument.
When I try to execute this code with the 2 arguments i get an empty output.

```
var fs=require('fs');
var path=require('path');
var filepath=process.argv[2];
var ext="."+process.argv[3];

fs.readdir(filepath,function(err,list) {
  if (err) throw err;
  for (var i=0;i<list.length-1;i++) {
    if (("."+path.extname(list[i]))==ext) {
      console.log(list[i]);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? What are you expecting and what do you actually get? Please edit your question to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, delete 'utf-8', you just need type (and read docs http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_callback):

```
 fs.readdir(filepath,function(err,list){
```

Comment: Thank you I fixed it. But still, I don't get the correct output.

Comment: delete -1 in for cycle and use program like my example - 'node index.js node_modules/ejs .js'. In my case output is 'benchmark.js
ejs.js
ejs.min.js
index.js'

Comment: Thank you. But, If I want to get the second argument(the extention) without a dot? txt Instead .txt

Comment: just write if (path.extname(list[i])==ext){

Comment: "The callback gets two arguments (err, files) where files is an array of the names of the files in the directory excluding '.' and '..'. " What I understood is that I get an array with the filenames without the dots.

Answer (score 0):

`path.extname()` returns an extension with a dot as seen here: [link](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_extname_path); there's no need for `"."+path.extname`.
`list.length-1` in your for loop doesn't make much sense when you consider how you've initialized your loop. `list.length` is the correct choice.

For reference on how to solve this problem, please see code below

```
var fs = require("fs")
var path = require("path")
var pathToUse = process.argv[2]
var ext = "."+process.argv[3]

fs.readdir(pathToUse, function(err, files){

if(err){
  throw err;
}
else{
var filteredFiles = files.filter(function(file){

    if(path.extname(file) === ext){
      return true;
     }
    else{ 
         return false;
        }
});
for(var x = 0; x < filteredFiles.length; x++){
console.log(filteredFiles[x];
}
}
});
```